# WSO2 Identity Server: Automatically adding users to roles on sign-up

Tags: wso2, roles, wso2-identity-server

I'm working on upgrading from WSO2 Identity Server 4.1.0 to 4.5.0 and I've found that new users are now added to an internal/identity group instead of the in LDAP identity group that they were being added to formerly.

In particular I would like to add new users to the LDAP group (I've got a lot of things that expect and need accounts to be in that group). But it brings up another question, is there anyway to define groups / roles that a new user automatically gets added to during sign-up?

Comment: have you tried editing file user-mgt.xml? by default all users are in the everyone role: <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName>

Comment: No, I haven't tried changing that. What I'm seeing is that users are implicitly part of the internal/everyone role. They are being explicitly created by the identity server as being part of internal/identity instead of the external identity role as they were previously.

I see no mention of identity in user-mgmt.xml

Comment: As an update, yes I did just try this. I can't get users to add to the system if I update that property to identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users who are signing up would be added in to a Internal/identity role by default in 4.5.0. This internal role is created in the internal databases.  Basically the user management database which has been defined in user-mgt.xml file.(UM_HYBRID_ROLE table).  This is because, This role is created pragmatically,  therefore is not good to create in the actual user store.  I guess WSo2 Identity Server has not way to configure this role name and configure where it must be retrieved.  I saw this as some limitation.

Comment: So... you're saying it's not possible to get the same or similar behavior from 4.5.0 that 4.1.0 had?

Comment: It has been identified as an issue [1] I guess, we need to patch the 4.5.0 to fix this issue. You can tract on this issue, When patch is available, you can use it..... [1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-1862

Comment: Issue is fixed.  You can find the patch from the jira. You need to add new configuration element to identity.xml file and can define a desired role name there.  [1]https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-1862

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, I'll do some testing on this today!

Comment: I suppose I should ask (since that Jira doesn't mention it) how is this applied? Do I shutdown the service and just replace the relevant jar file?

Comment: Yes.. Please backup the original jar file which can be found at <IS_HOME>/repository/components/plugins directory. And then replace with attached jar file.  Please note..  this is not a official patch and just a jar file to test. Patch applying process is little bit different than this. :)

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly! :) Now, to get this rolled out to my production environment.